# ¿Cuáles son los valores no válidos para la propiedades de estilos en IE9?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-v4.js

Tengo un js que usa la librería D3, en concreto la versión 4. Todo funciona correctamente en Chrome, Firefox e incluso en IE Edge y IE 10. Aun así necesito que funcione para IE 9/8.

En el sitio en inglés ya se hizo la pregunta [Making d3.js compatible with IE8/IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828501/making-d3-js-compatible-with-ie8-ie9), pero la versión D3 no es la misma y a mí no me funciona correctamente. ¿Alguien me lo podría explicar en español? Me ayudaría mucho.

En IE 9 me da este tipo de errores:

> SCRIPT87: Argumento no válido.
>
> Archivo: d3.min.js, Línea: 2, Columna: 6430

Y en IE 8 estos:

> SCRIPT438: El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'scaleLinear'
>
> Archivo: grafico.js, Línea: 2, Columna: 1

---

El error que me da usando el script "d3.js" me lleva a esta función de la librería:

```
function styleConstant(name, value, priority) {
  return function() {
    this.style.setProperty(name, value, priority);
  };
}
```

En concreto marca esta linea como error:

```
this.style.setProperty(name, value, priority);
```

Si uso d3.min.js me da el error en esta función:

```
function B(t,n,e){return function(){this.style.setProperty(t,n,e)}}
```

En concreto marca esta linea:

```
this.style.setProperty(t,n,e)
```

Descarto que sea mi código el que me da los errores ya que en el resto de navegadores funciona correctamente y los errores que me aparecen solo tienen que ver con las librerías D3.

He podido encontrar respuestas muy poco claras respecto al tema como [IE9: d3_style_prototype.setProperty occasionally throwing exceptions on svg elements](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2519), en la que se dice.

> Yes, IE9 throws an error sometimes if you try to set an invalid style property. This is one of IE9’s quirks, and since D3 is not a compatibility layer, you’ll need to avoid invalid values when setting style properties.

¿Cuáles son los valores no válidos para la propiedades de estilos?

Comment: @Rubén es verdad, gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya he encontrado como resolver el problema.

Para empezar, respondiendo a mi segunda pregunta.Los valores no validos para las propiedades de estilos son cualquier valor que poniendolo en los atributos css de error, es decir, si por ejemplo pongo:

```
.clase{
    background-color:"sudhuaioyd";
}
```

Me dara ese tipo de error, en este caso, `"sudhuaioyd"` es un valor no valido para las propiedades de estilos. Ademas, hay que tener en cuenta que si el navegador soporta la propiedad de estilo, que es ahi donde estaba mi problema.

Respondiendo de manera mas especifica a mi error. Esto me pasa a mi cuando por ejemplo desde d3 intento asignar una propiedad de estilo no valida para IE9 como podria ser:

```
var c1 = grupo.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)");
```

Como IE9 no soporta el valor rgba, me devuelve error, pero como lo estoy haciendo con la libreria de D3, me devuelve el error en el punto en el que la libreria intenta asignar este valor.

Ahora bien, para solucionar este error tengo dos opciones.

1. Mostrar por consola las propiedades de estilo que estoy intentando poner, y a la hora de que salte el error comprobar que propiedad de estilo es la que esta fallando y cambiarla en mi script.
2. Modificar el script de D3 para que cuando intente asignar una propiedad de estilo que no es compatible con IE9 la cambie o la omita.

Como ultimo detallar que hay una [web](http://caniuse.com/) en la que es posible comprobar si puedes usar un estilo u otro para los distintos navegadores que puede ser muy útil

### EDICIÓN

Después de configurar algo mas mi script y hacer pruebas, también he conseguido poder usar esas propiedades de estilo que no podía. Esto se debe a como instancias esa propiedad (como atributo o estilo).

Si en d3 ponemos:

`.style("stroke-width",15)`

En IE9 no funcionara, pero en cambio, si lo ponemos asi:

`.attr("stroke-width",15)`

Si que funcionara y no devolverá ningún error.

Answer (score 1):

> NOTA: Esta respuesta corresponde a la [revisión 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/59985/2) de la pregunta.

## Respuesta corta

De acuerdo a la [documentación wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki), Internet Explorer 9 está dentro de los entornos soportados, por lo que deberías publicar una pregunta más específica siguiendo las indicaciones de [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

## Información adicional

La [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16828638/1595451) en [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) a su vez hace referencia a la [documentación wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) de d3.js en la que supuestamente se sugiere el uso de [aight](https://github.com/shawnbot/aight), sin embargo, yo no encontré tal sugerencia. Por el tiempo que ha pasado, podría deberse a una actualización de la documentación.

De la [documentación wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) referida arriba, (énfasis mío, véase la fuente original para ver los enlaces incluídos):

> #### Supported Environments
>
> D3 supports so-called “modern” browsers, which generally means
>   everything except IE8 and older versions. D3 is tested against
>   Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, **IE9+**, Android and iOS. Parts of D3 may
>   work in older browsers, as the core D3 library has minimal
>   requirements: JavaScript and the W3C DOM API. D3 uses the Selectors
>   API Level 1, but you can preload Sizzle for compatibility. You'll need
>   a modern browser to use SVG and CSS3 Transitions. D3 is not a
>   compatibility layer, so if your browser doesn't support standards,
>   you're out of luck. Sorry!
>
> D3 also runs on Node and web workers. To use the DOM in Node, you must
>   provide your own DOM implementation; JSDOM is recommended. To avoid
>   defining a global document, pass a DOM element to d3.select or a
>   NodeList to d3.selectAll, like so:
>
> ```
> var d3 = require("d3"),
>     jsdom = require("jsdom");
>
> var document = jsdom.jsdom(),
>     svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg");
> ```

Comment: En un principio yo tambien tenia entendido como que D3 es compatible con IE pero no se si es por la version o que pero me tira error. Actualizo la pregunta para intentar ser mas especifico con los errores.